# three.js to webGL to OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, three.js, webgl

I want to take a three.js code and possibly convert it to a webGL or preferably OpenGL code so that I can use it in a stand-alone program that I'm developing in Python. Is there any straightforward way of doing that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any easy way.

Though if you know OpenGL, where "knowing" is when you can do pretty much any task, from rendering a huge amount of vertices to performing texturing, lighting and shadow mapping, etc.

Then you could simply go to any Three.js og WebGL application.

Here is a Three.js application as an example.

- http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube

Then you can just view-source of the Three.js/WebGL script. Where you automatically can make sense of most of it. Like.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 200, 300);
```

We can easily assume the above code would create a 3D Cube where `(100, 200, 300) = (width, height, length)`. Now we know that we need to create a new `VAO` and/or `VBO` which we would calculate the vertices, and as we can see in the example the cube is textured, so we know that we need to store both vertices and texture coordinates within the buffer.

Basically you could read through everything like that. Here are some more examples.

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

That would of course set the size of the display.

Also [Three.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threejs) is just a JavaScript library build on top of [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

Comment: Great. Is there any library on top of OpenGL (similar to three.js) which makes things easier for OpenGL programmers ? I just don't want to spend a lot of time on doing things in plane OpenGL. The 3D visualization of my results is barely 20% of my whole project and I would prefer using some libraries instead.

Comment: I don't really follow what you mean, could you explain it better?

Comment: or well yes there are a lot of OpenGL wrappers and utility libraries. Though I don't understand what you mean with "I just don't want to spend a lot of time on doing things in plane OpenGL" ? Well if you don't want to use OpenGL for rendering then, well try using something else I guess.

Comment: Actually the results of my codes are a bunch of coordinates which should be connected to demonstrate some sort of tracts. Imagine you are given the coordinates of control boxes of 1000 bezier curves. I have to visualize all these curves in a 3D interactive manner. I have a proper code which does it using three.js and WebGL. I have to do the same task in Python and that's why I am looking for a good 3D rendering library in python which is not as complicated as OpenGL. Do you know of anything in that regard ?

Comment: Ohh now I get it. Well hmm, not really I've specialize in OpenGL so I mainly use OpenGL of course. Though there is also DirectX but that is also an advanced library like OpenGL. It would also be impossible to say whether you should learn OpenGL or DirectX non of them are more easier than the other. Though if you want to make your program cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, Solaris, Android, etc) then choose OpenGL, because DirectX only exist on devices running Windows.

Comment: Just to throw my hat in the ring, and in 2020, there isn't anything really comparible to three for any other programming langauge or environment. I was shocked to find this, after really wanting to work in python (to not have to jump language when working with scientific visualisation techniques, 3d modelling, or even realtime engines) and after assessing about 6-8 tools, nothing comes close to just working in three. I am really happy working in large js codebases and have almost no problems with the langauge itself, I work between js and py all day. if you can work with js, use three.